# Maxim MAX3485ESA+T vs SP3485EN-L/TR

Tags: rs485, transceiver, modbus

I have a question about the [MAX3485ESA+T](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3483-MAX3491.pdf) RS485 Transceiver.

I ordered a PCB with a MAX3485ESA+T and the project doesn't work. The previous design was with a [SP3485EN-L/TR](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/146/sp3485-1816391.pdf) and it worked well, but I had a reliability problem with the chip; many of them were faulty.

So I decided to work with the MAX3485ESA+T although it is three times more expensive. Unfortunately, all the PCBs I ordered with the MAX3485ESA+T do not work. When I replace the MAX3485ESA+T with the SP3485EN-L/TR the circuit works properly.

Is it possible that all MAX3485s are faulty, or could there be some difference in the design of the circuit?
[image]

As suggested, I took out my old scope and made some measurements. The signals coming out of pin 1 RO is nice and clear, but in the MAX3485 I get positive pulses,
[image]

and from SP3485 the I get negative pulses,
in the SP3485 I also get negative pulses synchronized with RTS pin 2 and 3, that I do not have with MAX3485
[image]

so I guess something in the code needs to be changed to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Is it a drop-in replacement equivalent device ?

Comment: What if the problem is elsewhere in the circuit, and the other chip can handle the problem better than the other? How the chips are connected to the bus, do devices share a common ground reference, and what is the purpose of the mystery 1k2 resistor? What bit rate is used? How were they faulty? What device is driving the transceiver?

Comment: the problem is that the SP3485EN is working and the MAX3845 don't. the chip is connected to one device with a very sort cable about 1 meter long. It is connected to a Soil Sensor that measures the humidity, temperature, and EC  of the soil.

Comment: Please understand that we can't possibly know what do you mean by "does not work", and it is still not clear if you have made the connections properly or not. Which soil sensor it is, how is RS485 connected to it, what device is running your transceiver, how are they powered, so they share ground reference or not? If you don't mention these things then we can't narrow down what is the problem.

Comment: I'll second @Justme. This looks suspiciously like you're doing something to the chip that's out of spec. The one part can handle it somewhat as an edge case (some work, some don't - hence "reliability issues"). The other part totally can't handle it.

Comment: Do you have access to the scope? Can you check the signal on the bus (AB lines) for both drivers and compare? And, as others have mentioned, why do you have 1.2k on the bus?

Comment: the power of the sensor is 5v and for the chip is 3.3v and the ground is common. the 1.2k is on the PCB nir the chip. in the prototype, I use https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10124 So I used their design, the same chip, and the same resistor

Comment: The resistor is not 1.2k, that's wrong by factor of 10. Sparkfun board had 220 ohms. Which is incorrect too, but only by less than a factor of 2.

Comment: Eli, (I believe) that we all agree that the problem is almost certainly not in the RS485 transceiver. You might get your system to work with a particular chip/batch, but that would only hide/postpone the problem which you probably have on the system level.
To deal with that you need to do some extra debugging work, if you want people to help, you can start with sharing a more detailed diagram/schematic including the whole bus, sensor, and microcontroller that you have.

Comment: Generally Maxim are high quality and Sipex/Maxlinear (the new name always makes me laugh) are lower quality budget drop-in replacements. So if the MAX parts don't work, I would start to check soldering and suspect scammers. Who did you buy the parts from, some Alibaba scammer or a well-known distributor?

Comment: @EliSaadon what bit rate is your communication running at? Can you show us a 'scope trace of what the RS485 A and B lines look like while your devices are attempting to communicate?

Comment: in the schematic of Sparkfan the resistor is 220 home but if you check it on the board is actually 1.2k. the resistor is not the problem because I use a very short cable, I tried resistors of 220 110 56 had no effect

Comment: The bit rate of the communication is very low 9600. you can look at the photos that I added,

Comment: Judging by the scope pictures this is some simple problem like mixing up B and A signals (or soldering the SO8 backwards...?). For incoming data you'll also need a pull-up on RO no matter which part you use. Also as seen in the Maxim datasheet you should have resistors as in the examples on p9, for example the one in Figure 7 where they use 60R between the differential output signals.

Comment: One other thing to watch out for is how you are driving the RTS pin? Make sure you have sufficient delays, as per datasheet, when you toggle the RTS pin to either state. Especially careful one should be with switching the transceiver from the driver to the receiver state, because you need to ensure that the last sent character has been fully transmitted on the bus before switching to the receiver mode, on the other hand, if you stay in the driver mode for way too long, you might lose first few receiving characters.

Comment: Check that you have either an external pullup resistor on RO, or that you've enabled a pullup on that pin in your microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

After reading everyone's answers I came up with a solution to the problem.
First conclusion: SparkFun did a very bad job with [their board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10124).
As said by Lundin it must be a pullup resistor on RO pin no matter which part you use.
But adding a pullup resistor to MAX3485 was not enough to solve the problem, I need to add bias resistors to the inputs, from pin A to VCC, and from pin B to GND. I put a 10k resistor. (I have seen different values for these resistors starting from 720 to 20K, so 10k works well for me.) It looks like the SP3485 can work without those resistors.
I also found that the SP3485 chips that did not work were not faulty, adding 10k pullup resistor on pin RO solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both are compatible but your wire length and inductance and insulation capacitance determines impedance can distort the signals badly.  So use STP wire all the way and show all layout details in photos and schematic. Prove to  us you followed all the directions. (found elsewhere for RS-485 use)

Also DCDC supply are common mode noise ***generators***. If one at each end-device, big problems unless shield is terminated at Protective Earth (PE gnd) at host end. Then the differential 485 can work best, as designed. with 54Ω on each or  110Ω as a differential terminator load to match impedance of cable.  I suggest CAT5 cable. or make short twisted cable with twisted pair with spare pair twisted as well connected to PE ground wire at one end ONLY for short connection test.  Add terminator R. Measure voltages .

Even 5 cm of un-twisted pair wire will cause problems > 10MHz ringing.

- typical voltage output swing with no load will be 0 volts to 3.3 Volts.

With a load of 54Ω across the differential outputs, the drivers
can maintain greater than 1.5V voltage levels.

If you had low CM noise then shield is not necessary.